# Does do Carmo prove the Gauss-Bonnet theorem in his "Riemannian Geometry" text?

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry

I have seen that he has proven it in the "Differential geometry of curves and surfaces" text, but I am wondering if he also proves it somewhere in his "Riemannian Geometry" text.

Comment: Nope...........

Comment: There is a pretty easy way to check. Look through the book :)

Comment: I don't have the book here with me, but if you're looking for a reference with this Theorem proved, you could get the book "An introduction to riemannian geometry" written by Godinho, L. Natario, J.